# How to close BrowserView / BrowserWindow 's WebContents in Electron?

Tags: electron

How to destroy / close `BrowserView` / `BrowserWindow` 's `WebContents` ?

I tried to use, as suggested here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26929 destroy()  but I get

```
TS2339: Property 'destroy' does not exist on type 'WebContents'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just because the `destroy` method wasn't added to the typings since it's meant to be an undocumented, internal function.

Notice, the error you're getting is a Typescript compilation error, not a runtime error.

Type assert to `any` and it should work: `(webContents as any).destroy()`

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. Thank you very much @pushkin